2 Apps / Multi-window emulator in Android Studio
I have 2 Android Automotive OS apps on my emulator and I was wondering if it's possible to run and display both in 2 separate windows?
They are 2 modules of the same project and are installed on the emulator.
Thanks!

How are you defining "2 separate windows"? Do you mean two copies of the emulator? Do you mean some form of split-screen or freeform multi-window experience within Android Automotive? Or do you mean something else?

@CommonsWare I just want to see both apps running at the same time for demo purposes, so whichever way works

Then it seems like you should set up two separate emulator instances, and show one app on one instance and show the other app on the other instance.

@wiswasi just create two emulater and run both at the same time and it will work..then iinstall the apps seperately on both emulater.

I already tried that... I wanted to show both apps simultaneously in 2 separate windows. When both apps are running, it only shows one at a time and I have to switch between them.
